# Why can't MongoDB connect to my NodeJS app?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, localhost, database-connection

In nodejs server, mongodb isn't connecting. The error code on terminal showing

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started on port 5000
MongoParseError: URI does not have hostname, domain name and tld
    at parseSrvConnectionString (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:41:21)
    at parseConnectionString (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/uri_parser.js:516:12)
    at connect (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:266:3)
    at ConnectOperation.execute (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:191:5)
    at executeOperation (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:83:26)
    at MongoClient.connect (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:216:10)
    at /home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:632:12
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:629:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:328:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/psayeed1990/programming/node/node_passport_login-master/app.js:18:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1128:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  name: 'MongoParseError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
```

This is the code to connect

```
dbPassword = 'mongodb+srv://sayeed:'+ encodeURIComponent('123456') + 'mongodb://localhost:27017/node-passport-login';

module.exports = {
    mongoURI: dbPassword
};
```

The full nodejs app was taken from Traversy Media's github page Node Passport Login.

Comment: Remove +srv and it'll become mongodb://localhost:27017; srv looking for tld for cluster mongodb.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced this issue, I updated my password using autogenerate password,
it worked for me.

```
EXAMPLE

If your password in plain-text is p@ssw0rd'9'!, you would need to encode your password as:

p%40ssw0rd%279%27%21
```

https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password

Comment: Yup, thanks. I had a special character too that I didn't realize was causing my.

Answer (score 1):

The mongodb connection url you have provided is incorrect, which in your case is the dbPassword.
If you want to connect to a locally hosted mongodb database then do the following.

Start mongod in a terminal and the change the dbPassword to the local url like this

```
dbPassword="mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName"
```

or you can use the url directly inside app.js like this

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName")
```

If this is not what you want and you want to do what Brad did which is to connect to a cloud database you need to first make an account on mongodb cloud, login and then create a cluster after which you need to  copy the URL.

It's easier to use the local mongodb server in my opinion.
You only need cloud databases once you wish to deploy your application.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am having a ec2 instance and want to deploy it there with nginx and a domain name. So will the url you have given work for that? Why don't I need the user and password for the local database? Is it secure in a production level?

Comment: I want to use MongoDB locally in ec2 instance.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using the free tier available with mongodb cloud. If that is the case then simply login to your account https://account.mongodb.com/account/login and then click on connect, then click on connect your application, there you will see the connection string, simply copy paste that and replace the password section with your password for mongodb cloud and you should be good to go

Comment: I mean I have installed mongodb in a ec2 instance. Then after uploading my node app there, I have to connect the db. The string you have provided works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had '*' and '#' at the end of the password string. I also didn't want to use auto generated password.

Before:

```
password*#
```

After:

```
password%2A%23
```

You can use online tool to url encode your password

https://www.url-encode-decode.com/